# Mean of a Pearson Type VI distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, inference, expected-value

I have a question that gives me the density of a Pearson type VI distribution and then says to state the range of parameter(s) for which the expression for the mean is valid.  In your calculations, you may use the fact that the density integrates to 1 for all feasible parameters. Here we have that $\alpha>0$, $\beta>0$, $\lambda>0$.
$$f(x) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\lambda^\beta{\frac{{x^{\alpha-1}}}{(\lambda+x)^{\alpha+\beta}}}$$
If somebody could shed some light as to how to do this I would be very thankful?

I also cannot provide much more information about the question because the above information is all that I am given. My attempts so far have been to integrate $$\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)}\lambda^\beta\int{{\frac{{x^{\alpha}}}{(\lambda+x)^{\alpha+\beta}}}}dx$$

I am not sure where to really begin with this question, my lecturer hasn't put up many examples to help me with this. I was first considering manipulating the integral and trying to re-express the integral in terms of a Gamma, or beta or something that is easier to spot. However I have not had any luck trying to simplify this problem.

Comment: Hint: by virtue of the defining relation $\Gamma(\alpha+1)=\alpha\Gamma(\alpha)$ the integrand for the expectation, $xf(x;\alpha,\beta),$ is easily related to $f(x;\alpha+1,\beta)$--and you already know its integral from the "fact" provided in the question.

Comment: So what is the range of parameters that I am supposed to get?

Comment: I don't understand your question: the mean is a *number* rather than a range of parameters.  This number will, of course, potentially depend on $\alpha,$ $\beta,$ and $\lambda.$

Comment: The question asks me to state the range of parameters for the expression of the mean is valid

Comment: OK. There are two approaches: one is to compute the mean and see for which parameter values your formula makes sense.  Although this often works, it's not rigorous.  The rigorous way is to determine those parameter values for which the integral converges absolutely. Since $\lambda$ is positive, there's no problem at the lower limit of $0,$ so all you have to do is examine the asymptotic behavior of the integrand as $x\to\infty.$